# In Borderlands, what is the fastest way to get 5 seconds of hangtime in a vehicle?

Tags: borderlands

I'm starting fresh and seeing if I can complete bigger challenges earlier on to net large amounts of experience for a low-level character. Out of these challanges, the hang-time in vehicle challanges seem like they would be particularly easy to net.

Because of this, I'm curious: What's the earliest point in the game where one can net the 5 second hang-time achievement? If you don't know if your suggested location is the earliest location, that's fine; I have never gotten the 5 seconds of hangtime achievement and so would like to know where it can be gotten regardless of time spent reaching the location.

Comment: I got the first 2 levels of the hang-time challenges by using the ramps in Dahl Headlands whenever I was driving about. Even with a little dedication it took a while. Not sure if there are better places to get it - Hence not posting an answer ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Melee off Piss Wash Gully (Earliest opportunity)

If you have a partner Melee your vehicle while you're in it on the Piss Wash ramp, that also unlocks it. ([Youtube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQPk6N9q_Ck))

#### Dahl Headlands

I've gotten it in the Dahl Headlands off the beginning Ramp.  You've got to be lined up perfectly.

#### Rust Commons East

There's a bridge near the Middle of Nowhere that (at one point) during the game is lowered for you (I believe it's on the mission to go to Janistown);  If you talk to the Claptrap, and then back up the racer, you'll get insane air if you jump the bridge while it's about 50 degrees or better.

#### General Knoxx's Armory

The highways in the Sunken Sea provide good opportunities. The easiest way to do it is to get in the racer and launch your self off the left end of a broken road (where the curb hits the road). The hitting of the curb makes you go higher and makes it more likely.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer :D  It's very much appreciated. I'll be trying these out tonight :3

Comment: A great answer!

Comment: Mêlée off Piss Wash Gully is how speed-runner Youkai did it too.

Answer (score 1):

I did it by sliding the runner on its side while it was moving. This gave me the achievement even though it was a glitch. It it is very difficult to do, but you can do it as soon as you get the runner.

Comment: Hey superslayer, Welcome to Arqade! Thanks for taking the time to answer a question! I edited your answer to improve clarity; if you feel that it doesn't convey the same message, then feel free to revert the edit.

Comment: Also, have you ever repeated this glitch? If it's repeatable, do you think you could get us a screenshot?